# Git rebase from certain commits

Tags: git

It is really difficult to understand `Git rebase` for beginner. I always get weird result when I `rebase`. I found that I can use `--onto` to control where I should rebase to, but how can I control the `from` side?

For example:

[image]

Let's say I am at branch 2 now, the number represent the time when the commit is done, and red color is my branch-2 commits which are not in master yet. If I want to get my branch 2 become below, what command should I use?

1) 1 -> 2 -> 8 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7

2) 1 -> 2 -> 8 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7

In the beginning, I thought this can't be done, because my commit 3 will be gone, but I read it from Git website, this is actually valid.

[image]

3) 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 7

Can I do this? Basically to rebase only commit 7 on top of master?

The reason of asking these are because, auto `rebase` always give me headache, so I rather to be able to specify, I want to rebase `from` which commit `onto` which commit. Am I able to do so? But I can't find the `from` parameter.

Comment: It’s advisable to put the branch labels in the correct place. A branch points to _one_ commit.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hi, I don't quite get it, can you elaborate further?

Comment: If you look at the diagram from the git docs, you can see the branch names point to commits. `master` points to `C6` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First case:

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase máster
```

Second case:

```
git rebase --onto master branch2~3 branch2 #rebase branch2 but skipping revision 3
```

Third case:

```
git checkout branch2~
git cherry-pick master #pick revision 8
git cherry-pick branch2 # pick revision 7
# if you like the result
git branch -f branch2
git checkout branch2
```